# Using Python's stat function to efficiently get owner, group and other permissions

Tags: python, permissions, stat, octal

## Question:

How do I efficiently use the [stat](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html) function to get meaningful file permissions (User, Group and Other).

## Details:

I am querying the file permissions like so:

```
statInfo = os.stat
permissions = stat.S_IMODE ( os.stat ( 'fooBar.txt' ).st_mode )
```

This returns the permissions in decimal form. So if `fooBar.txt` has the octal file permissions `0700`, here `permissions` is set to the decimal value`448`. What I want is to set 9 variables for each permission (`ownerRead`, `ownerWright`, `ownerExecute`, `groupRead`,...) If I was going to do this, I'd use a brute force method like so:

```
statInfo = os.stat
permissions = stat.S_IMODE ( os.stat ( 'fooBar.txt' ).st_mode )
octPermissions = oct ( permissions )

ownerRead = octPermissions [1] >= 4
ownerWrite = octPermissions [1] == 2 or octPermissions [1] == 6 or octPermissions [1] == 3 or 
ownerExecute = octPermissions [1] == 1 or octPermissions [1] == 5 or octPermissions [1] == 3
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this without having to convert to octal as this function will get called quite a bit?

Comment: You only need to mark names as `global` if you are going to alter them. Since I doubt you'll be modifying the `os` and `stat` modules, you do not need to mark them as `global` anywhere.

Comment: oops, my bad, I copied this from inside a function

Comment: I know, I guessed. Let me tell you again: You do not need to declare these `global` as they will be looked up from the module scope automatically without that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the bitwise AND operator:

```
m = os.stat('fooBar.txt').st_mode
otherExec  = bool(m & 0001)
otherWrite = bool(m & 0002)
otherRead  = bool(m & 0004)
groupExec  = bool(m & 0010)
groupWrite = bool(m & 0020)
groupRead  = bool(m & 0040)
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Use bitwise AND and the constants in the [`stat` module](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html#stat.S_ISUID):

```
import stat
import os

mode = os.stat('fooBar.txt').st_mode

otherRead  = bool(mode & stat.S_IROTH)
otherWrite = bool(mode & stat.S_IWOTH)
otherExec  = bool(mode & stat.S_IXOTH)
...
```

So much more readable.

Comment: dang it, I just finished perfectly aligning my `0100`'s and `0010`'s

Answer (score 3):

I've put this together into a function that gets UNIX permissions:

```
import os
from stat import (S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR, S_IXUSR, S_IRGRP, S_IWGRP,
                  S_IXGRP, S_IROTH, S_IWOTH, S_IXOTH)

def bit2int(bit):
    return int(oct(bit))

def convert_st_mode(st_mode):
    bits = (S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR, S_IXUSR, S_IRGRP, S_IWGRP, S_IXGRP,
            S_IROTH, S_IWOTH, S_IXOTH)
    mode = "%03d" % sum(int(bool(st_mode & bit)) * bit2int(bit) for bit in bits)
    return mode

def get_unix_permissions(pth):
    mode = convert_st_mode(os.stat(pth).st_mode)
    return mode
```

Usage:

```
mode = get_unix_permissions("somefile")
print(mode)
```